# How to convert a list of lists of tuples into a pandas DataFrame as time efficient as possible?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have as input a list of lists of tuples, like below:

```
[[("apple", "dog", 5), ("banana", "cat", 32.3), ("pineapple", "horse", 33)], [("apple", "dog", 0), ("pear", "dog", 8), ("pear", "cow", 5.5)], [("apple", "dog", 7), ("banana", "dog", 4)]]
```

I want to convert this to a pandas DataFrame that contains a list column for each entry of the tuples. So one column containing all the first elements in a list, one column containing all the second elements in a list, and so on...

I know I can create a pandas DataFrame consisting of 1 list-of-tuple type column like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[("apple", "dog", 5), ("banana", "cat", 32.3), ("pineapple", "horse", 33)], [("apple", "dog", 0), ("pear", "dog", 8), ("pear", "cow", 5.5)], [("apple", "dog", 7), ("banana", "dog", 4)]]})
```

But I don't know how to convert this to (in this example) a 3 column DataFrame.

The desired output would look like this:

```
first                            second                    third
["apple", "banana", "pineapple"] ["dog", "cat", "horse"]   [5, 32.3, 33]
["apple", "pear", "pear"]        ["dog", "dog", "cow"]     [0, 8, 5.5]
["apple", "banana"]              ["dog", "dog"]            [7, 4]
```

How to solve this as time-efficient as possible? My real DataFrame will contain about 1M rows so I would prefer the fastest solution possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` to format the data prior to putting it in to a DataFrame.

```
pd.DataFrame([zip(*row) for row in data], columns=["first", "second", "third"]).applymap(list)

                        first             second          third
0  [apple, banana, pineapple]  [dog, cat, horse]  [5, 32.3, 33]
1         [apple, pear, pear]    [dog, dog, cow]    [0, 8, 5.5]
2             [apple, banana]         [dog, dog]         [7, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can this be easily converted into a list variant? I now I could separately change each column with a lambda function but I suspect this could be done more elegantly

Comment: @Peter chain `.applymap(list)` maybe

Comment: @anky no sure the speed of applymap

Answer (score 1):

A python option:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [("apple", "dog", 5), ("banana", "cat", 32.3), ("pineapple", "horse", 33)],
    [("apple", "dog", 0), ("pear", "dog", 8), ("pear", "cow", 5.5)],
    [("apple", "dog", 7), ("banana", "dog", 4)]
]

df = pd.DataFrame([map(list, zip(*row)) for row in data],
                  columns=["first", "second", "third"])

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
                        first             second          third
0  [apple, banana, pineapple]  [dog, cat, horse]  [5, 32.3, 33]
1         [apple, pear, pear]    [dog, dog, cow]    [0, 8, 5.5]
2             [apple, banana]         [dog, dog]         [7, 4]
```

---

Performance Python `map` + `list` vs `applymap` via perfplot:

[image: perfplot timings]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

np.random.seed(5)

in_zero = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
in_one = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'horse']


def gen_data(n):
    in_lst = []
    for _ in range(n):
        in_lst.append(np.array([
            np.random.choice(in_zero, 3),
            np.random.choice(in_one, 3),
            np.random.random(3) * 33,
        ]).transpose().tolist())
    return in_lst


def pure_python(data):
    return pd.DataFrame([map(list, zip(*row)) for row in data],
                        columns=["first", "second", "third"])


def apply_map(data):
    return pd.DataFrame([zip(*row) for row in data],
                        columns=["first", "second", "third"]).applymap(list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    out = perfplot.bench(
        setup=gen_data,
        kernels=[
            pure_python,
            apply_map
        ],
        labels=[
            'pure_python',
            'apply_map'
        ],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(20)],
        equality_check=None
    )
    out.save('perfplot_results.png', transparent=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will still use `pandas` function `explode`

```
s = df.explode('A')['A']
out = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
                            0                  1                  2
0  [apple, banana, pineapple]  [dog, cat, horse]  [5.0, 32.3, 33.0]
1         [apple, pear, pear]    [dog, dog, cow]    [0.0, 8.0, 5.5]
2             [apple, banana]         [dog, dog]         [7.0, 4.0]
```